Trigger incremental search for user defined command arguments
When incsearch is enabled, doing a search with / or entering the search pattern for the substitute command will highlight the pattern as you type.  Is there a way to get this same behavior for custom commands?  I'd basically like to define a command so that doing :MyFancySearch somestr will highlight all occurrences of "somestr" even before I press enter to run the command.  The help for incsearch mentions some other built in commands that trigger this behavior, but doesn't mention anything about custom commands, so perhaps it's not possible, but I was hoping I missed something.

Immediately after posting the question, I read a bit further down in the incsearch help and found mention of CmdlineEnter and CmdlineLeave autocmd events.  It turns out there's also a CmdlineChanged event that is fired whenever the current command line changed.  With that, I was able to come up with the following, but it feels rather janky:
function! CustIncSearch()
    let cmdName = '^MyFancySearch\s'
    let cmdLine=getcmdline()
    if cmdLine !~# cmdName
        return
    endif
    let pattern = substitute(cmdLine, cmdName, '', '')
    let @/=pattern
    set hlsearch
    redraw
endfunction

augroup CustIncSearch
  autocmd!
  autocmd CmdlineChanged : call CustIncSearch()
augroup END

My main issue is that it gets triggered for any change to the command line instead of only for my desired command, so the function has to filter for the specific command which feels a bit wasteful (but maybe it's not a huge deal).  I tried autocmd CmdlineChanged :MyFancySearch call CustIncSearch(), but that doesn't appear to be valid (according to the help, <afile> is only a single character that specifies the type of the command line).
Also, it doesn't more prominently highlight the next occurrence after the cursor like it does when searching normally, but that's less of a concern for me.
Perhaps someone else has a better suggestion.

afaik filtering like that is typical

Thanks for the confirmation, @D.BenKnoble.  Perhaps I won't fret about it then.
